# What is the use of two or more User.Name in Git. 

Tags: git

I'm a novice in Git and I have started learning Git by using the free online [book](http://progit.org/book/). I have few doubt to clear:

I have used this command to set up my Git:

```
$ git config --global user.name "Anto"
```

Later on I just used this command:

```
$ git config user.name "anto aravinth"
```

(that is without the `--global` option)

And now when I run with the following command:

```
$ git config --list
```

I'm getting the output as:

```
user.name=Anto
user.email=anto.aravinth.cse@gmail.com
push.default=matching
color.status=auto
color.branch=auto
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=true
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
user.name=anto aravinth
```

In the above command I can see two `user.name` field with the values `anto` and `anto aravinth` respectively. So whats the point of two `user.name` here? To allow more than one user on the same system or what else? As I'm a novice it will be good if the answer is simple enough.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in [`git config` man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/git-config):

- environment variables like `GIT_AUTHOR_NAME` and `GIT_COMMITTER_NAME` will override local config (config within a current repo)
- local config will override global config (config within `$HOME/.gitconfig`, which supposes you have define an environment variable `HOME`, knowing that it isn't defined by default on Windows)
- global config will override system config (config  within the git installation directory itself)

Note that `git config --list --local` can have several error message:

```
fatal: unable to read config file '.git/config': No such file or directory
```

(if done outside of a git repo directory)

```
error: unknown option local
```

(if done with git1.7.1 or less *and* run outside a git repo, as illustrated by this [git-dropbox ticket](https://github.com/agnoster/git-dropbox/issues/1). The [solution](https://github.com/agnoster/git-dropbox/commit/492bd9c8f0e4f89be07449903c6500c4ad1c411e) was to ignore the error message:

```
 DROPBOX_REPO=`git config --local dropbox.repo 2>/dev/null`
```

)

Answer (score 2):

Global configuration options are listed first, followed by local ones. If you run

```
git config --list --global
git config --list --local
```

You should see `user.name` listed only once for each. The latter config options (local ones) override global config options.

Comment: if i run the second command `git config list --local` i'm getting an error!

Comment: Error message when I ran both : `error: key does not contain a section: list`

Comment: @KugathasanAbimaran: for me the first one is working properly.. But the second command is failing with the same error message that you have posted!

Comment: @KugathasanAbimaran sorry about that, it's too late for me to be thinking properly, I've updated my answer.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall: UPDATED?? Again I'm getting the same error! :(

Comment: @Ant's What version of Git are you running? Are you sure it's not a different error? `--list --local` can give a "No such file or directory" error if there is no local configuration to read.

Comment: @Ant's I don't know what to say… I'm running v1.7.7.4 (latest release), and `git config --list --local` runs for me.

Comment: You could try `git config --get --local|--global|--system user.name`, or just give up and look in .git/config (local), ~/.gitconfig (global), and /install-location/git/config (system).

Comment: @Jefromi: Ok fine.. Let me give me :D